# Use the password in file to decrypt GnuPG-encrypted file

Tags: python, gnupg

When I write `status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase='password', output='output.txt')` in python.
I can decrypt the file.

When I write `password='password'
status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=password, output='output.txt')`
I can also decrypt the file.

But when I write

```
ff = open("4.txt",'rb')
temp = ff.readline()
password = temp[0:len(temp)-2]
status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=password, output='output.txt')
```

I cannot decrypt the file as `temp` is `password\r\n` , so the `password` is 'password'

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried `temp = temp.rstrip('\r\n')` to remove the carriage return and newline?

Comment: Did you double-check that `password` holds the correct value? (Also, why use `rb` to read a text file?)

Comment: I didn't get any error. It just cannot decrypt the file.
I tried temp = temp.rstrip('\r\n'), but it didn't work.
I print password=='password', and it is True. But it cannot decrypt the file.

Answer (score 0):

- Use text mode for reading streams that you know are text.
- Rely on “universal newlines” of text input streams.
- Use string type methods for manipulating character strings.

```python
passphrase_infile_path = "lorem.txt"
with open(passphrase_infile_path, 'r') as passphrase_infile:
    passphrase_line = passphrase_infile.readline()
    passphrase = passphrase_line.rstrip('\n')
```

That way the passphrase should work, because you have just those characters without the line break.

```python
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
crypto_infile_path = "ipsum.gpg"
plaintext_outfile_path = "dolor.txt"
with open(crypto_infile_path, 'rb') as crypto_infile:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(
            crypto_infile,
            passphrase=passphrase,
            output=plaintext_outfile_path)
```

---

First, note that `temp[0:len(temp)-2]` is more idiomatically written as `temp[:-2]`.

This expression gets all but the last two items of the sequence `temp`.

Since `temp` is a sequence of bytes, you will *always* trim off the last two bytes of that sequence.

```python
>>> line = b'rabbit\r\n'
>>> line[:-2]
'rabbit'
>>> line = b'rabbit\n'
>>> line[:-2]
'rabbi'
```

That's not the reliable way to trim off the line break from an input line.

Instead, open the file in text mode, and you'll get normalised line breaks and text input. Then, use the `str` built-in methods to manipulate it by characters.